# Return multiple values in Java

Tags: java, function, return

I wrote a function in Java and I want this function to return multiple values. Except use of array and structure, is there a way to return multiple values?

My code:

```
String query40 = "SELECT Good_Name,Quantity,Price from Tbl1 where Good_ID="+x;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
if (c!= null && c.moveToFirst()) 
{
  GoodNameShow = c.getString(0);
  QuantityShow = c.getLong(1);
  GoodUnitPriceShow = c.getLong(2);
  return GoodNameShow,QuantityShow ,GoodUnitPriceShow ;
}
```

Comment: What matters isn't "Eclipse" but the language (Java).

Comment: I realise your code is pseudo-Java, but ensure you name your variables with camelCase (e.g. `goodNameShow` or `goodUnitPriceShow`).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Java, when you want a function to return multiple values, you must

- embed those values in an object you return
- or change an object that is passed to your function

In your case, you clearly need to define a class `Show` which could have fields `name`, `quantity` and `price` :

```
public class Show {
    private String name;
    private int price;
    // add other fields, constructor and accessors
}
```

then change your function to

```
 public  Show  test(){
      ...
      return new Show(GoodNameShow,QuantityShow ,GoodUnitPriceShow) ;
```

Comment: @estiedi Do you mean that `Collection.sort` is bad style ? You can't make efficient code if you try to make it understandable by people who don't know the most basic facts of the language. If somebody doesn't know that a received object can be changed by a method, then he must learn before being involved in a professional team.

Comment: It's still regrettable that languages didn't learn from the CLU example.  CLU's related multiple assignment is of semi-dubious use (`x,y = y,x`), but multiple return values is **very** useful (`x,y = function(params)`).  Forcing a wrapping object to be returned (often by "clean" declarations similar to `class Pair<A,B>`)has a penalty under very many tight calls, and passing an object to hold return values is horribly messy with no compiler guarantee that the fields are filled.

Comment: @tgm1024 You should have a look at Go where bot returning multiple values and multiple assignements are very useful ;)

Answer (score 2):

One quick and ugly approach I encountered a few times (even in java library itself) is to return your values as `Object[]` and then unpack using casting.
e.g.

```
public Object[] myfunc() {
  String name = "...";
  Integer quantity = 5
  Float price = 3.14
  return new Object[] { name, quantity, price };
```

Then, it is used like this:

```
Object[] output = myfunc();
String name = (String) output[0];
Integer quantity = (Integer) output[1];
Float price = (Float) output[2];
```

Embedding the values in a dedicated object is much cleaner, but I leave it here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a very basic approach to deal with this kind of situation.

I have used a logic of **seperator** in Strings.

For example if you need to return in the same function
1. int value
2. double value
3. String value

you could use a **separator string**

**For example ",.,"** this kind of string would not generally appear anywhere.

You could return a String consisting of all values separated by this separator
**"< int value >,.,< double value >,.,< String value >"**

and convert into equivalent types where the function has been called by using  **String.split(separtor)[index]**

Refer the following code for explanation -

separator used =",.,"

```
public class TestMultipleReturns{

 public static void main(String args[]){

   String result =  getMultipleValues();
   int intval = Integer.parseInt(result.split(",.,")[0]);
   double doubleval = Double.parseDouble(result.split(",.,")[1]);     
    String strval = result.split(",.,")[2];
 }

 public static String getMultipleValues(){

   int intval = 231;//some int value      
   double doubleval = 3.14;//some double val
   String strval = "hello";//some String val

   return(intval+",.,"+doubleval+",.,"+strval);

 }
}
```

This approach can be used as a shortcut when you do not want to increase number of classes for only function returns

It depends on situation to situation which approach to take.

Comment: Although this suggestion does not increase the number of classes, it is a horrible approach for many reasons: You create multiple unnecessary objects (`StringBuilder`, `String`s) which are far more expensive than a single instance of a utility class. The effort of retrieving the values is unjustifiable large, requires unnecessary code and has a noticeable impact on the performance. As you already noticed, the separator must not appear in the string and that is usally an unjustifiable assumption.

Comment: I downvoted just so people never actually uses this approach. It's bad for performance and readability, and the calee never know what to expect from a return like that.

Comment: @still_learning - I know that this approach is very bad as far as performance is concerned, but that was just a part of practice that I had done when I had started with programming.
I mostly worked on julia and matlab where you can return multiple vals like, return var1,var2 etc... So when I started off with JAVA I had just done as a part of practising. I actually thought that it would work good but then I felt later that it gives very poor performance.