# Returning multiple values java

Tags: java

Say I have a java function as follows,

```
public static int my(int a, int b)
{

    int c = a + b;
    return c;

    String d = "Some Data";
    return d;

    float f = a/b;
    return f
}
```

So, how do I get the 3 return values separately?

all the values are of different data types.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393490/return-multiple-values-in-java) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609269/best-practice-for-returning-multiple-values-in-java) but couldn't understand properly.

Comment: create a class which can hold 4 values `a,b,c,d`. in the function `my` create an instance of the class and set the values of `a,b,c,d` and return the object

Comment: What part of the answers to those linked questions was unclear?

Comment: You can only return once, and you can't return multiple values. The answers you linked provide solutions. Returning an int[] array or some collection also works.

Comment: Doing things using an object is more reliable and better anyway.

Comment: you can also create list<Integer> or map<operation,Integer> and return value.

Comment: Make separate methods for each math operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

any function can only return one value. What you can do is to create an objet containing all your answers and return this object.

```
class ResultObject
{
   public int c;
   public int d;
   public int e;
   public int f;
}
```

in your function white

```
public static ResultObject my(int a, int b)
{
ResultObject resObject = new ResultObject();
resObject.c = a + b;

resObject.d = a*b;

resObject.e = a-b;

resObject.f = a/b;
return resObject;
}
```

You can return only one value. You have to make that value to "contain" other values.

Comment: Yes this is the right way. And use of getter methods will be more appreciated in this regard

Comment: say I want to access only f..how to do that in my action class?

Comment: ResultObject r = my(5, 10); System.out.println(r.f);

Answer (score 1):

return array of int.. e.g. int[]...

```
public static int[] my(int a, int b) {
    int res[] = new int[4];

    int c = a + b;
    res[0] = c;

    int d = a * b;
    res[1] = d;

    int e = a - b;
    res[2] = e;

    int f = a / b;
    res[3] = f;

    return res;
}
```

Comment: `new int[4]` for four values.

Comment: you will get indexOutOfBound exception. new int[3]. updated your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

1. If you returning uniform values, e.g. hundred values for temperature over a period of time - **use arrays**.
2. If values are non-uniform, e.g. first name, last name and age - **introduce a new class**.

Reason for this is that Java is a strongly-typed programming language. Wanna describe a new data structure - write a new class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
  public static int[] my(int a, int b) { // use an array to store values
    int[] arr = new int[4];
    int c = a + b;
    arr[0] = c;

    int d = a * b;
    arr[1] = d;

    int e = a - b;
    arr[2] = e;

    int f = a / b;
    arr[3] = f;

    return arr; // return values 
}
```

Comment: Please check my edit, what to do if the return types are of different data types?

Answer (score 0):

You can return only one element but the element may be array or list.you may return list of values.(some exercise). I hope this may bring some solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DataStorage{
         private int a;
         private String data;
         private float f;

         public DataStorage(int a, String data, float f){
             this.a = a;
             this.data = data;
             this.f = f;

         }

         /* standard get/set method. */
     }
```

---

```
    public static DataStorage my(int a, int b)
    {

       int c = a + b;


       String d = "Some Data";


       float f = a/b;


        DataStorage dataStorage = new DataStorage(c,d,f);
        return dataStorage;
    }
```